# custom UIcollectionViewCell, using view to control color changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I was going thru the tutorial here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-build-a-uicollectionview-in-ios-8/

And saw a part that looked great because it makes something simple, use of views to show color changes of selected/unselected items.-

```
(void)awakeFromNib {

    // background color
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.backgroundView = bgView;
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue"]];

    // selected background
    UIView *selectedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink"]];
}
```

The author showed that this is a simple approach that eliminates the need to manage the state of the cells.

Q. I want to change the color using this method during the highlight process. However, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath is in the CollectionViewController and I'd like to have it use the same process.

Basically what it does is change from one color to another based on selected/unselected.  I'd like to use the add a color to indicate the in between state of being highlighted/unhighlighted.

I checked all the methods that are in cell that use UIView, and there is nothing for highlighted/unhighlighted.

Any ideas on an approach that has the advantages of using cell methods?  Can I call a custom method from the viewcontroller method and load a view there?

You might think of this as a "press and hold" that changes the color when it's being held.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIView` wouldn't know anything about it's selected or unselected state since it's a very elemental component and not specific to controls that allow selection.  The `UICollectionViewCell` does have a `selected` property though, so that would be the right place to change these characteristics.  Looking at the docs it seems like either tapping into `setSelected` or `selectedBackgroundView` would give you a good opportunity to customize the L&F of selected cells.  There's also a `highlighted` state in case you might also be looking for that.